# tigervnc not connecting with localhost

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, vnc-server

stuck from a couple of days. In ubuntu i'm creating vncserver with command line [tigervnc]

```
vncserver -localhost yes
```

to secure connection from only localhost.
vnc is successfully created with port - 5901.

Im using putty to establish SSH tunnelling,

[image]

SSH tunnel

[image]

in realVNC viewer in using

```
localhost:9091
```

**But it gives error saying connection refused.**

1. I want to establish a SSH tunnel with only localhost in order to avoid the brute force attack, getting too many authentication failure errors.

What am i doing wrong. Please guide me.

Note : connection works fine if i use `vncserver -localhost no`. But for security reasons i dont want this

2. to allow connection from localhost only and to avoid brute-force attack in these any settings need to change in vnc-config or something.

Did a hell of research, couldn't resolve. StackOverflow is the last hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Localhost is `127.0.0.1`

You have to create SSH TCP FORWARD to `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`), not `103.16.26.144`

There is how I use this on my linux desktop, from a shell terminal.

```
ssh -fL 9091:localhost:5900 user@103.16.26.144 sleep 2 &&
    xvncviewer localhost:9091
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding! I use Windows to connect through putty. what i sould be writing in source port and destination port ? I tried - source port = 9091 and destination port = localhost:5901.  No luck. error = connection refused from computer,

Comment: can you please take a look at question - 2 as well ?

Comment: If "`@103.16.26.144`* you run `vncserver -localhost yes -rfbport 5900`, you have to connect by forwarding `9091 -> localhost:5900`, then connect you local client by `vncviewer localhost:9091`. And yes this prevent port 5900 to be reachable from other network interface than *`lo`*

Comment: How to prevent port 5900 to be reachable from another network interface than lo?

Comment: `vncserver -localhost yes`